# How to express current row and current row +1 in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I have a window sql that want to sum the current row with the next, so I write the following sql:

```
  select depName, empNo, salary, sum(salary) over (partition by depName order by empNo rows between CURRENT ROW AND CURRENT ROW + 1) sum_salary  from t
```

But there is grammar error in it,

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
missing ')' at '+'(line 2, pos 136)

== SQL ==

          select depName, empNo, salary, sum(salary) over (partition by depName order by empNo rows between CURRENT ROW AND CURRENT ROW + 1) sum_salary  from t
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to define row-based frame is

```
ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING
```

and similarly

```
ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

You can also replace numeric constant with `UNBOUNDED` keyword.